# How to prevent redistribution of content bought online

Tags: piracy-prevention, piracy

Is there a way to prevent content (media) files from being used by anyone except those actually paying for the content? At this point I am thinking of e-books created with the use of FlippingBook software, or e-books in the form of PDF files, downloadable from a web site. What I want is that only the person purchasing the content file will be able to open/view it, but if he/she shares it with others, those will not be able to.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. (If I am in the wrong forum, sorry, please redirect me to the correct place.)

Comment: This is wayyy to broad for Stack Overflow or any of its associated sites - it's basically the question the entire content industry has been asking itself for the past fifteen years. I'd just Google the various DRM options available, check out their pros and cons. Short version: anything that really works has massive shortcomings. It's certainly worth considering not using any copy protection, and living with some amount of piracy. Or publish in one of the walled gardens (Amazon/iTunes store/etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I work for a copy protection company. I will try my best not being biased by my work.

Yes, protection is possible. Some will say that it's not worth it and you should focus on making your product better, rather than wasting money on copy protection. This is true in some cases, but not in all. A good copy protection will increase sales, as people can't share your product with each other. Some countries and products are more exposed than others, so make the choice you believe is best for the success of your products.

The keyword you should be searching for is "Copy protection". My advice for you would be search the web for "copy protection" vendors if you want a professional product. Make a list of those you trust the most and contact them.

If you choose a professional product, test the protection carefully, and in many ways. Badly made protection can cost you customers, due to unhappy customers and support issues. These cases of badly made protection is what have made many users hate DRM, copy protection and etc...

If you on the other hand don't want to pay for it, but are searching for freeware, then I can't give any good advice as I don't know any. If you want to make one your self then you should read this post: [All About Copy Protection](http://linkdata.com/theory.htm) it might be old but still valid for copy protection today.